# SSL Pinning on iOS - TLS caching issue with NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, caching, ssl, pinning

I have encountered an issue when implementing pinning of our SSL certificate on iOS app. We are currently using `NSURLConnection` with a delegate for Authentication Challenges. This is all good, and gets called on initial login for the app, ensuring that we are connected to our server.

We are aware of the TLS caching, where the pinning delegate method (**willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge**) is not called again for a period of 10 minutes. This is not an issue really, as we only need to check the certificate on login, although more frequently would be desirable. We raised a support ticket with Apple and received a response confirming that TLS caching would mean the pinning delegate method would only be called periodically, but that a cryptographic key exchange would prevent MITM proxy attack from happening between calls.

Sounds good, however this does not seem to be the case. Here's what we've discovered - If we log into our app as normal on start up, the pinning delegate is called. We then background the app and connect the iPhone to a proxy server on macbook running Burp Suite (server trust certificate is already installed on the iPhone at this point). If we then foreground the app, log out and log back in again, willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge is not called, even though the TLS session should be invalid at this point.

I have tried specifying different caching policies on the request, but doesn't seem to make a difference. I can't understand why the delegate would not be called again with the MITM proxy added - any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Solved it. We had an additional heartbeat ping to the server on foregrounding that didn't have our delegate in place, so was using the system default for authentication challenges. As the fake SSL certificate being presented looked ok to the system level check, this was enough to cache the new TLS setup for 10 minutes, meaning that on the subsequent login call, our pinning delegation was not being called. Hope this helps someone in the future.